# how to compare the string with array in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm having a hard time comparing arrays.  The data in the array is coming from API.  I have set the data in state and given it to Flatlist and compare it in renderitem.

i am also trying with loop and simple view but its not working.
if any body know please let me know.

in console log when i console the data is show data properly. with true values

Api  code is:
**

```
const [eventsData, setEventsData] = React.useState([]);
  useEffect(()=>{
    AsyncStorage.getItem('Login_row').
    then(val => {
        if (val == null) {
            setloader(false);
            navigation.navigate('LoginScreen');
        } else {
            const login_row = JSON.parse(val);
            // console.log(login_row.access_token);
            reFresh(login_row);
        }
    });
},[]);
const reFresh= (login_row) => {
  Server.get('api/getuser/all',{
    headers:{
        'Authorization': `Bearer ${login_row.access_token}`
    }
}).
then(res => {
    // console.log(res.data);
    setEventsData(res.data);
    console.log(res.data[0].status)
    setloader(false);
}).
catch(err => {
  alert(err);
  setloader(false)
});
}
```

**
here is my renderitem code

```
const myfun = (item) => {
   
      if (item.status === 'Approved')
      {
        return(
          
           <View style={styles.container}>
            <View style={{width:'90%'}}>
              <Text style={styles.title}>ID:{item.id} </Text>
              <Text style={styles.desc}>Name: {item.fname} {item.lname}</Text>
              <Text style={styles.desc}>Email: {item.email}</Text>
              <Text style={styles.desc}>CNIC: {item.cnic}</Text>
              <Text style={styles.desc}>Phone: {item.phone}</Text>
              <Text style={styles.desc}>Status: {item.status}</Text>
           
            </View>
           
        <View style={{width:'10%',alignItems:'flex-end',alignSelf:'center'}}>
          <Icon onPress={()=>{setModalDel2(true);setIdDel(e.id)}}
          style={{marginBottom:10,color:'#86eb7c',}} active name="checkcircleo" type="AntDesign"  />
          <Icon style={{color:'#ff9d96',}} active name="closecircleo" type="AntDesign" />
        </View>
       </View>
        )
      }
  
}
```

flatlis code is:

```
<FlatList
          style={{flex:1}}
            data={eventsData}
            renderItem={ myfun}
            keyExtractor={(item) => item.id.toString()}
          />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
const myfun = ({ item }) => {
  if (item.status === "Approved") {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={{ width: "90%" }}>
          <Text style={styles.title}>ID:{item.id} </Text>
          <Text style={styles.desc}>
            Name: {item.fname} {item.lname}
          </Text>
          <Text style={styles.desc}>Email: {item.email}</Text>
          <Text style={styles.desc}>CNIC: {item.cnic}</Text>
          <Text style={styles.desc}>Phone: {item.phone}</Text>
          <Text style={styles.desc}>Status: {item.status}</Text>
        </View>

        <View
          style={{ width: "10%", alignItems: "flex-end", alignSelf: "center" }}
        >
          <Icon
            onPress={() => {
              setModalDel2(true);
              setIdDel(e.id);
            }}
            style={{ marginBottom: 10, color: "#86eb7c" }}
            active
            name="checkcircleo"
            type="AntDesign"
          />
          <Icon
            style={{ color: "#ff9d96" }}
            active
            name="closecircleo"
            type="AntDesign"
          />
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
  return null;
}
```